# How to create arraymap that accepts different data types?

Tags: java, arrays, dictionary

I want to insert string and array into one ArrayMap

```
String str = "Hello";       
String[] mArray = new String[]{"aaa", "bbb", "ccc"};

/* This is Arraymap that accepts only string*/

ArrayMap<String, String> data = new ArrayMap<>();
data.put("a", str)    ;  
data.put("b", mArray);
```

Comment: Is this Java? Please add the language tag.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what an ArrayMap is so I'm going to assume you mean HashMap. Should be the same idea.

You can create a map of Object objects! Every class is automatically a subclass of the [Object class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) in Java.

```
ArrayMap<String, Object> data = new ArrayMap<>();
data.put("a", str);
data.put("b", mArray)
```

Alternatively, you can create a class that contains both String and Array fields that you can set and use that class as the data type.